# Escaping URL encoding for external links

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

In my application, I have an editor which allow users to compose formatted emails. Everything works except when they have some urls having special characters being used as hyperlinks. For example

```
this is a link. <a href="http://www.somesiteurl.com?token=xO53C3hjLhMyL%2BDF42Dft8I8W%2F7dqTnPCHnqhgQyz6%2BcqzAMmv40mQa1BSqUa8Z4HM6E8tgrBxz1Yfiox188BJZQvmZgN18tb%2FINpP0XQydHCy27UQDp0u%2BvcZBYkQoDoQ72LxWU%2FWD3FM49vSV%2F8yciYjMpaWiVxlg2bX7TzYg%3D">Click Here</a>
```

As you can see the token contains characters which are utf-8 encoded elements like +,/ and + sign.
How I can avoid them getting decoded while rendering. 
The rendered url becomes

```
http://www.somesiteurl.com?token=xO53C3hjLhMyL+DF42Dft8I8W/7dqTnPCHnqhgQyz6+cqzAMmv40mQa1BSqUa8Z4HM6E8tgrBxz1Yfiox188BJZQvmZgN18tb/INpP0XQydHCy27UQDp0u+vcZBYkQoDoQ72LxWU/WD3FM49vSV/8yciYjMpaWiVxlg2bX7TzYg=
```

Hence the link does not work correctly. I do not have any control how users create this url.

Comment: I've tested the following code on http://cflive.net: `<cfset link = "this is a link. <a href=""http://www.somesiteurl.com?token=%2B%2F%2B%2F%2B%2F%2F%3D"">Click Here</a>  
"><cfoutput>#link#</cfoutput>` The URL in the html is not decoded. Therefore, I'm unable to reproduce your problem. What exactly is meant with _rendering_ in your case?

Comment: @StefanBraun, let me try explaining this way. An application user composes an email in the editor. I do not have any control what content user uses in the text. The actual hyperlink is part of the email. But when the system sends email, in the recipient email box that link changes and does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are confusing UTF-8 with URL encoding/decoding.  It looks like you are doing a urldecode when you should just be passing through the URL unchanged.  Take a look at the following snippet which plays around with your token just a bit:

```
<cfset token="xO53C3hjLhMyL%2BDF42Dft8I8W%2F7dqTnPCHnqhgQyz6%2BcqzAMmv40mQa1BSqUa8Z4HM6E8tgrBxz1Yfiox188BJZQvmZgN18tb%2FINpP0XQydHCy27UQDp0u%2BvcZBYkQoDoQ72LxWU%2FWD3FM49vSV%2F8yciYjMpaWiVxlg2bX7TzYg%3D">
<cfset tokendecoded=urldecode(token)>
<cfoutput>
token unchanged gives: token = #token#<br />
tokendecoded gives:  token = #tokendecoded#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

For me, this gives the following output:

```
token unchanged gives: token = xO53C3hjLhMyL%2BDF42Dft8I8W%2F7dqTnPCHnqhgQyz6%2BcqzAMmv40mQa1BSqUa8Z4HM6E8tgrBxz1Yfiox188BJZQvmZgN18tb%2FINpP0XQydHCy27UQDp0u%2BvcZBYkQoDoQ72LxWU%2FWD3FM49vSV%2F8yciYjMpaWiVxlg2bX7TzYg%3D
tokendecoded gives: token = xO53C3hjLhMyL+DF42Dft8I8W/7dqTnPCHnqhgQyz6+cqzAMmv40mQa1BSqUa8Z4HM6E8tgrBxz1Yfiox188BJZQvmZgN18tb/INpP0XQydHCy27UQDp0u+vcZBYkQoDoQ72LxWU/WD3FM49vSV/8yciYjMpaWiVxlg2bX7TzYg=
```

So you may want to URL encode the token before you send it.  Then decoding it would work fine.  If you want to take the token as it is being passed, then don't decode it.  Your choice.

Comment: More on URL encoding (also known as percent encoding) at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gerry. But my problem is this token is part of a href which is being sent as an email. So when the email lands in inbox %2B is converted to a "+" sign, %2F to a "/" and so on. I do not have any control over the formation of original url.

Comment: Can you access the raw non-html portion of the email?  There is a separator in the raw email that gives you access to the html part and the text part.  It should have the same text.  Hopefully it isn't decoded.